# Multinomial distribution: Is there a way to compute the probability of having identical match up to n errors?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, multinomial-distribution

Given an alphabet $A = \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ where the letters are not equiprobable, and two separate random word drawn from $N$ letters, is there a way to compute the probability that these two words would match up to $n$ errors?

Despite all my efforts I don't see any solution. However, since I am no expert, I want to know if there is a way to solve this analytically before I tackle it with a no-brain bootstrap approach.

Comment: Hint: Can you find the probability that the first letter in the first word matches the first letter in the second word?  Call that a success. Then think about the Binomial distribution.

Comment: Oooh! I think I get it. The probability of success should be $P(sucess) = \sum_{a \in A} p_{a}^2$ right ? Then $P(fail) = 1 - P(sucess)$ and I can view the whole thing as a Binomial distribution like you suggested.
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in reading about the "index of coincidence": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence